# Stream throw exception if any element is found not satisfying criteria otherwise process the stream

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a better way to filter/map below:

```java
list.stream()
  .filter(o -> !(o instanceof Person))
  .findAny()
  .ifPresent(o -> { throw new RuntimeException(); });
```

```java
list.stream()
  .filter(o -> o instanceof Person)
  .map(o -> o.getName())
  .toList();
```

I want to process all elements of list which are instance of a class say `Person` and if any element is not instance of `Person` then I want to throw exception. Wanted to know if there is someway to combine the above statements so that I wouldn't need to stream the list twice?

Comment: The second one is not really doing anything. What do you really *want* it to do?

Comment: Why not just try the cast and let it throw `ClassCastException` if there is a non-map? Or, if you want to throw a different exception, do the instance-of check and throw-or-cast logic in the `map` operation.

Comment: The second part can be anything, let me update the question

Comment: Your edit, if anything, has made it worse ;) What I was going to get at is to use the size of the `List`s to avoid a double streaming but I don't even know if that's relevant, as I can't know. Not enough detail

Comment: Check the new edit it makes sense to you

Comment: BTW, you can write `.map(o -> o.getName())` as `.map(Person::getName)`

Comment: OK. That makes sense, and fits in with what I was saying. Stream the `List` once and throw the exception if your collected `List` is smaller. But as @Slaw said, if your intention is to throw an exception anyway, why not then allow the natural exception to occur? This, of course, illustrates the weakness of allowing mixed types in collections

Comment: In other words, what's wrong with simply doing `list.stream().map(Person.class::cast).map(Person::getName).toList()`? It will throw an exception if an element cannot be cast to `Person`.

Comment: Or `list.stream() .map(o -> ((Person)o).getName()) .toList();` Besides that, the idiomatic solution to check for a condition is, e.g. `if(list.stream().anyMatch(o -> !(o instanceof Person))) { throw new SpecificException(); }` or as others said, a `ClassCastException` can serve as a specific exception so, `list.forEach(Person.class::cast);` will do.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
list.stream()
    .peek(o -> {
        if (! (o instanceof Person)) throw new RuntimeException();
    })
    .map(o -> ((Person) o).getName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```